# JSdom canvas - how to take screenshot of a page?

Tags: node.js, canvas, jsdom

*VERSIONS:*

```
node v8.11.4
"express": "^4.16.3",
"jsdom": "^11.3.0",
"request": "^2.88.0",
```

*CODE:*

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');
var jsdom = require("jsdom/lib/old-api.js");

var page = request('https://www.ggole.com', function(err, resp, content) {
    jsdom.env(
    {
        html: content,
        done: function (err, window)
        {
            if (err) {console.log(err);}
            var document = window.document;
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            var data = canvas.toDataURL();
            window.close();
        }
    });
}
```

*PROBLEM:*

I would like to take a screenshot of google page. Is this possible with JSdom? Content of the page is in canvas tag so how to make a picture from it and send it to the user/edit it?

var data = canvas.toDataURL(); is not working as expected. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

may be it's late :)
jsdom uses nodejs canvas as the external dependency
their documentation say

> Canvas support jsdom includes support for using the canvas package to
>   extend any  elements with the canvas API. To make this work,
>   you need to include canvas as a dependency in your project, as a peer
>   of jsdom. If jsdom can find the canvas package, it will use it, but if
>   it's not present, then  elements will behave like s.
>   Since jsdom v13, version 2.x of canvas is required; version 1.x is no
>   longer supported

and you can find examples how to use canvas here
https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas